# getting error while using "buildozer android debug"

Tags: android, python-3.x, ssl-certificate, kivy

[getting this whenever i enter "buildozer android debug"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Djd0.png)

iam trying to generate apk using kivy buildozer and always end up with error.
it cannot download its requirements(packages). getting an SSL certificate error.Please help.